# Qsort parallel arrays using pointers

Tags: c++, 2d, qsort

I am trying to do a parallel qsort in C++ .  I have numeric array which is sorting fine and I want a parallel 2 dimensional character array to move up or down with its numbers.  This is what I have so far.

```
    int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
    {
        //this is for qsort
        return ( *(int*)b - *(int*)a );
    }

    void sort_scores(char** myArray, int *votes)
    {
        qsort ((myArray, votes ), 5, sizeof(int), compare);
    }
```

I get a sort on the numbers but short of moving the characters one at at time I can't seem to get this to work. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind describing what's the problem you are solving? Sounds to me you could make use of `std::map` or a vector of some structures.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sorting the votes themselves, you could create an array of pointers to the votes (that is, an array of pointers to each element of the `votes` array), and sort the pointers. (Remember to update the comparing function accordingly! It will now receive arguments that you have to cast to `int **`).
After sorting that new array, just walk through it, and use pointer difference to get the indices of the elements in the original arrays.

Comment: I'm not sure if I was clear on my initial post of what I was trying to accomplish.  I am passing in an integer array, which sorts just fine and a two dimensional character array which is parallel.  This is homework so to remain in the spirit of the assignment I must use two separate arrays and do some sort of sort in parallel.  I have been explicit instructed not to use a class object and it must be a two dimensional character array.  I think I would be circumventing the essence of the learning experience if I just put them in a string array and number array and did a bubble sort.

Comment: In that case, the main problem you'll face is that `qsort` doesn't support that. You can either 1) sort the indices (like I suggested, or in any other way -- it's a very common technique, I'm sure you'll find enough information on it), or 2) write a new sorting function that exchanges elements in the parallel array as you exchange them in the main array. The latter is probably what you're looking for, but, as I said, it will require you to write a sorting function, since `qsort` won't help you with it.